# Async displaying markers with React-Google-Maps and Redux

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to render markers on a Google map from a React-Redux state but I'm getting the errors "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" and "Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null"

Here's my component:

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    APIManager.get('/api/hike', null, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        return
      }
      this.props.hikesReceived(response.results)
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('updated list of hikes ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.hikes))
  }

  render() {
    const hikes = this.props.hikes.map((hike, i) => {
      const hikeMarker = {
        latlng: {
          lat: hike.location.lat,
          lng: hike.location.lng
        }
      }
      return <Markey key={i} {...hikeMarker} />
    })

    return (
      <GoogleMapLoader
        containerElement = { this.props.mapContainer }
        googleMapElement = {
          <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={10}
            defaultCenter={this.props.center}
            options={{streetViewControl: false, mapTypeControl: false}}
            onClick={this.addMarker.bind(this)} >
             <Marker {...hikeMarker}/>
          </GoogleMap>
        } />
    )
  }
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    hikes: state.hike.list,
  }
}

const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    hikesReceived: (hikes) => dispatch(actions.hikesReceived(hikes)),   
  }
}

export default connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Map)
```

I know it's an async problem because the console.log() happens twice. The first time it's empty and the second time it renders with the data. The markers also display with no error when I'm using dummy data.

How do I go about telling the map to wait to render, or re-render, once there is data in this.props?

Comment: you could check for undefined/ empty data/ null or whatever and then just return false

Comment: I've tried "if (this.props.hikes == null || undefined) {return: false}" and it just renders the error twice

Comment: Actually, "false" worked. There was a variable naming problem between the front and back end. Thanks @elsololobo !

Answer (score 0):

Half of the problem was names changing in the database. The other half was solved with:

```
if (this.props.hikes == null || undefined) {return: false}
```